Let $z_1 > 3$, $z_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2}(z_n + \frac{3}{z_n})$. Show, that $(z_n)$ is decreasing and find $\lim_{n \to \infty} z_n$.
Showing, that it is decreasing, is already a problem for me.
As
$$z_1>3 \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad \frac{1}{z_1} < 3 \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad \frac{3}{z_1} < 9$$
then
$$z_2 = \frac{1}{2} \left(z_1 + \frac{3}{z_1}\right) < \frac{1}{2}\left(z_1 + 9\right) = \frac{1}{2}z_1 + \frac{9}{2}$$
But I don't know what to do next.
To show the limit, I would need to solve the recurrence equation $z_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2}(z_n + \frac{3}{z_n})$ first, and then take the limit. But I don't know how to solve it.
Could anyone help? I really don't know what to do here.

if you are allowed to use the number $\sqrt 3,$   show that $ (z_{n+1} - \sqrt 3 )^2  < (z_n - \sqrt 3)^2 $   but each $z_{n+1}  > \sqrt 3$

$$z_1>3 \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad \frac{1}{z_1} < \frac 13 \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad \frac{3}{z_1} <1$$

Will this help? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3853078

Proving that $z_n$ is decreasing:
By AM-GM inequality, it's easy to notice that for all $n \ge 2$
$$z_n = \frac{1}{2}\left( z_{n-1} + \frac{3}{z_{n-1}}\right)\ge \sqrt{z_{n-1} \cdot \frac{3}{z_{n-1}}} = \sqrt{3}$$
then
$$z_{n+1} -z_n = \frac{1}{2}\left(  \frac{3}{z_{n-1}}-z_{n-1} \right) \le 0$$
Limit of $ z_n$:
As $z_n$ positive and decreasing, the limit $l$ exists and satisfies
$$l =\frac{1}{2}\left( l + \frac{3}{l}\right)  \iff l = \sqrt{3} $$

It's helpful to write down what we want to show first:
$$
z_{n+1} < z_n 
$$
for all $n$ after some point, i.e., there's some positive integer $N$ such that the inequality holds for all $n \geq N$. This allows for some transitory behavior in the sequence before it settles into decreasing towards its limit.
So we want
$$
\frac12 \biggl( z_n + \frac{3}{z_n} \biggr) < z_n. 
$$
Let's suppose that $z_n > 0$. In fact, $z_n > 3$ for all $n$, but we haven't shown that yet. We can multiply through by $z_n$ without changing the inequality (multiply by $2$ as well to get rid of fractions). So we want
$$
z_n^2 + 3 < 2z_n^2
$$
or
$$
z_n > \sqrt{3}. 
$$
Remember that this is all scratchwork to derive conditions that we need in order to conclude that the recursive sequence is decreasing. So far, we've deduced that if $z_n > \sqrt{3}$ then $z_{n+1} < z_n$.
This means that if we can use the initial conditions and the recursive formula to show that $z_n > \sqrt{3}$ for all $n \geq N$, then we may conclude that the sequence decreases. But how to show this lower bound?
Again, we argue inductively. We are given that $z_1 > 3 > \sqrt{3}$, so that's a start. Again, let's look at what we want to show, and hopefully reduce it to something that we know is true:
$$
z_{n+1} > \sqrt{3} 
$$
or
$$
\frac12 \biggl( z_n + \frac{3}{z_n} \biggr) > \sqrt{3}. 
$$
After multiplying through by $2z_n$ (again, we must use the hypothesis that $z_n > 0$) and rearranging a bit, we see that we need
$$
z_n^2 - 2\sqrt{3}\,z_n + 3 > 0. 
$$
Miraculously, this expression is a perfect square, hence it must be positive (away from the limit)!
$$
\bigl( z_n - \sqrt{3} \bigr)^2 > 0. 
$$

Now, a formal argument would use all of the above calculations, which are essentially stated in reverse, and build an argument in the forward direction, which is summarized as:

Assuming that $z_1$ is positive, show that all $z_n > \sqrt{3}$ (bounded below).
Using the fact that $z_n > \sqrt{3}$, show that $z_{n+1} < z_n$ (decreasing).
By the Monotone Convergence Theorem, the sequence converges down to its limit: $z_n \to z$ as $n \to \infty$.
Find the limit $z$ by solving for the fixed point:
$$
\frac12 \biggl( z + \frac{3}{z} \biggr) = z.
$$

